# Number field edit is going into the loop

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have widget column, where I am using numberfield. Whenver I am trying to edit some data in numberfield it is going to `editRrecord` method but it is not  getting exit. It is keep going into the loop.

Any idea what I need to do here.

Here I am creating column :

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var wCol= {
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        text: me.data.list[i],
        dataIndex: me.data.list[i],
        flex: 1,
        widget: {
            xtype:"numberfield",
            someVal : me.data.value[i],
            listeners:{
                change : 'editRrecord'
             }
        }
    }
    widgetGrid.columns.push(wCol);
}
```

my editRrecord method.

```
editRrecord:function(editor, newVal, oldVal, index ){
        debugger;
        if(oldVal !== null){
            // Some operation
        }

    }
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vf8)

Here I have placed the debugger in change function, whenever I am changing, debugger is going multiple times and washed away the actual value.

Comment: Can you provide some small working code in some fiddle ?

Comment: @Tejas I have placed the fiddle Can you please have a look.

Comment: @JD I  have placed the fiddle Can you please have a look.

Comment: @David in the fiddle i cant see any loop, and its working fine over there, whenever you change the value it comes to the change function as expected.

Comment: @JD it is coming into the loop. means multiple time it is going.

Comment: please update the fiddle accordingly

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you want. The fiddle you've posted works as one would expect, I don't see any infinite loops or weird behaviour

Comment: @Laurens yes will update fiddle asap.